# How to tell if a webpage exists?

Tags: perl, networking, ping

Just for fun, I'm writing a Perl program to check if a given website exists. For my purposes, a website exists if I can go into my browser, punch in the url and get a meaningful webpage (meaning not an error or "failed to open page" message).  What would be the best way to go about doing this? Eventually I would like to be able to give my program a list of hundreds of urls.

I'm thinking about just pinging each of the urls on my list to see if they exist; however, I don't really know too much about networking so is this the best way to do it?

Comment: Sidenote: When your program is going to poll hundreds of websites, then perhaps consider honouring their [`robots.txt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) files.

Comment: @stakx, if you're only going to read one page from each site, and only do it once, then robots.txt is probably overkill.  If you're polling repeatedly, though, then you should be checking robots.txt.

Comment: @cjm: Agreed. Since the OP didn't say whether some server(s) would get queried more than once, I thought it was worth mentioning just in case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Library for WWW in Perl (LWP):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP::Simple;
my $url = 'http://www.mytestsite.com/';
if (head($url)) {
  print "Page exists\n";
} else {
  print "Page does not exist\n";;
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between doing this and just `pinging` the server?

Comment: The server may be available but it may not necessarily be serving out web content.

Comment: Not to mention that a server can ignore ping requests but still serve web content.

Comment: Technically it can honor GET requests but not HEAD requests, especially common in cgi environments.

Comment: True, if youre not using Apache or standard web browser then HEAD may not be supported. For this there are custom writtem 'head' modules that work off the GET request.

Comment: I am getting `Method not allowed`

Answer (score 1):

There is no such protocol as "pinging web pages" for existence. You actually have to request the resource and if it's served up, it exists. There are several ways to go about it, here are a couple:

1. [Retrieving web pages with LWP](http://perlmeme.org/tutorials/lwp.html)
2. Checking for an existing web page could as simple as:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env perl
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   use LWP::Simple qw(head);
   head('http://www.perlmeme.org') or die 'Unable to get page';
   ```

The same solution as command-line tool is [`lwp-request`/`HEAD`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?lwp-request). `HEAD` returns the resource headers, such as content size and will be quicker than getting all the page contents.

Comment: Wouldn't this be pretty slow because aren't we retrieving the entire contents of the webpage.  All I need is to know if they webpage exists.

Comment: You can use HEAD for fetch a web page summary rather than the whole page. See my edit.