# How to multithread seeing if a webpage exists in Perl?

Tags: perl, networking

I'm writing a Perl script that takes in a list of URLs and checks to see if they exist. (Note that I only care if they exist; I *don’t* care what their contents are. Here’s the important part of the program.

```
use LWP::Simple qw($ua head);

if (head($url))
{
    $numberAlive ++;
}
else
{
    $numberDead ++;
}
```

Right now the program works fine; however, I want it to run faster. Thus I'm considering making it multithreaded.  I assume that the slow part of my program is contacting the server for each URL; therefore, I'm looking for a way in which I can send out requests to the URLs of other webpages on my list while I'm waiting for the first response.  How can I do this?  As far as I can tell, the `head` routine doesn't have a callback that can get called once the server has responded.

Comment: Duplicate of own post [How to tell if a webpage exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594932/how-to-tell-if-a-webpage-exists)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Begin with familiar-looking front matter.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.10.0;  # for // (defined-or)

use IO::Handle;
use IO::Select;
use LWP::Simple;
use POSIX qw/ :sys_wait_h /;
use Socket;
```

Global constants control program execution.

```
my $DEBUG = 0;
my $EXIT_COMMAND = "<EXIT>";
my $NJOBS = 10;
```

URLs to check arrive one per line on a worker’s end of the socket. For each URL, the worker calls `LWP::Simple::head` to determine whether the resource is fetchable. The worker then writes back to the socket a line of the form *url* **:** *status* where *status* is either `"YES"` or `"NO"` and  represents the space character.

If the URL is `$EXIT_COMMAND`, then the worker exits immediately.

```
sub check_sites {
  my($s) = @_;

  warn "$0: [$$]: waiting for URL" if $DEBUG;

  while (<$s>) {
    chomp;
    warn "$0: [$$]: got '$_'" if $DEBUG;
    exit 0 if $_ eq $EXIT_COMMAND;
    print $s "$_: ", (head($_) ? "YES" : "NO"), "\n";
  }

  die "NOTREACHED";
}
```

To create a worker, we start by creating a [`socketpair`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/socketpair.html). The parent process will use one end and each worker (child) will use the other. We disable buffering at both ends and add the parent end to our IO::Select instance. We also note each child’s process ID so we can wait for all workers to finish.

```
sub create_worker {
  my($sel,$kidpid) = @_;

  socketpair my $parent, my $kid, AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, PF_UNSPEC
    or die "$0: socketpair: $!";
  $_->autoflush(1) for $parent, $kid;

  my $pid = fork // die "$0: fork: $!";
  if ($pid) {
    ++$kidpid->{$pid};
    close $kid or die "$0: close: $!";
    $sel->add($parent);
  }
  else {
    close $parent or die "$0: close: $!";
    check_sites $kid;
    die "NOTREACHED";
  }
}
```

To dispatch URLs, the parent grabs as many readers as are available and hands out the same number of URLs from the job queue. Any workers that remain after the job queue is empty receive the exit command.

Note that `print` will fail if the underlying worker has already exited. The parent must ignore `SIGPIPE` to prevent immediate termination.

```
sub dispatch_jobs {
  my($sel,$jobs) = @_;

  foreach my $s ($sel->can_write) {
    my $url = @$jobs ? shift @$jobs : $EXIT_COMMAND;
    warn "$0 [$$]: sending '$url' to fd ", fileno $s if $DEBUG;
    print $s $url, "\n" or $sel->remove($s);
  }
}
```

By the time control reaches `read_results`, the workers have been created and received work. Now the parent uses [`can_read`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Select.html#can_read-%28-[-TIMEOUT-]-%29) to wait for results to arrive from one or more workers. A defined result is an answer from the current worker, and an undefined result means the child has exited and closed the other end of the socket.

```
sub read_results {
  my($sel,$results) = @_;

  warn "$0 [$$]: waiting for readers" if $DEBUG;
  foreach my $s ($sel->can_read) {
    warn "$0: [$$]: reading from fd ", fileno $s if $DEBUG;
    if (defined(my $result = <$s>)) {
      chomp $result;
      push @$results, $result;
      warn "$0 [$$]: got '$result' from fd ", fileno $s if $DEBUG;
    }
    else {
      warn "$0 [$$]: eof from fd ", fileno $s if $DEBUG;
      $sel->remove($s);
    }
  }
}
```

The parent must keep track of live workers in order to collect all results.

```
sub reap_workers {
  my($kidpid) = @_;

  while ((my $pid = waitpid -1, WNOHANG) > 0) {
    warn "$0: [$$]: reaped $pid" if $DEBUG;
    delete $kidpid->{$pid};
  }
}
```

Running the pool executes the subs above to dispatch all URLs and return all results.

```
sub run_pool {
  my($n,@jobs) = @_;

  my $sel = IO::Select->new;
  my %kidpid;
  my @results;

  create_worker $sel, \%kidpid for 1 .. $n;

  local $SIG{PIPE} = "IGNORE";  # writes to dead workers will fail

  while (@jobs || keys %kidpid || $sel->handles) {
    dispatch_jobs $sel, \@jobs;

    read_results $sel, \@results;

    reap_workers \%kidpid;
  }

  warn "$0 [$$]: returning @results" if $DEBUG;
  @results;
}
```

Using an example main program

```
my @jobs = qw(
  bogus
  http://stackoverflow.com/
  http://www.google.com/
  http://www.yahoo.com/
);

my @results = run_pool $NJOBS, @jobs;
print $_, "\n" for @results;
```

the output is

```
bogus: NO
http://www.google.com/: YES
http://stackoverflow.com/: YES
http://www.yahoo.com/: YES
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend using [Parallel::ForkManager](https://metacpan.org/module/Parallel::ForkManager) instead of handling the process pool yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is HTTP::Async.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTTP::Request;
use HTTP::Async;

my $numberAlive = 0;
my $numberDead  = 0;
my @urls = ('http://www.perl.com','http://www.example.xyzzy/foo.html');

my $async = HTTP::Async->new;

# you might want to wrap this in a loop to deal with @urls in batches
foreach my $url (@urls){   
  $async->add( HTTP::Request->new( HEAD => $url ) );
  }

while ( my $response = $async->wait_for_next_response ) {
  if ($response->code == 200){$numberAlive ++;}
  else{$numberDead ++;}
  }

print "$numberAlive Alive, $numberDead Dead\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Worker-based parallelisation (using your choice of threads or processes):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );
use threads;  # or: use forks;

use LWP::Simple        qw( head );
use Thread::Queue::Any qw( );

use constant NUM_WORKERS => 10;  # Or whatever.

my $req_q  = Thread::Queue::Any->new();
my $resp_q = Thread::Queue::Any->new();

my @workers;
for (1..NUM_WORKERS) {
   push @workers, async {
      while (my $url = $req_q->dequeue()) {
         my $is_alive = head($url) ? 1 : 0;
         $resp_q->enqueue($is_alive);
      }
   };
}

$req_q->enqueue($_) for @urls;

my ($alive, $dead);
for (1..@urls) {
   my $is_alive = $resp_q->dequeue();
   ++( $is_alive ? $alive : $dead );
}

$req_q->enqueue(undef) for @workers;
$_->join for @workers;

say $alive;
say $dead;
```